# React nested route not rendering a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Could anyone share some light on why this Router configuration doesn't want to render the `Project` component while trying to access `to/design/project/whatever`?

```
<Route path="/" component={MainWrapper}>
  <Route path="to/design/" component={Design}>
    <Route path="project/:id" component={Project} />
  </Route>
  <Route path="to/code" component={Code} />
</Route>
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Do you get any error in console? Can you provide the code for `Project` component?

Comment: add some more details like console log, and index files

Answer (score 1):

I simply forgot to specify the `{this.props.children}` inside the `Design` component.